# Default PXRichTextEdit to Plain Text

Tags: acumatica

When viewing a PXRichTextEdit field in Acumatica, there is a dropdown at the top left of the control to change from Visual to Plain Text. Is there any way to have that control automatically default to the Plain Text option for new records?

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any property to do so.

The only property targeting this menu is `AllowSourceMode` which can hide the HTML menu item:

```
<px:PXRichTextEdit ID="edDescription" runat="server" DataField="Description" 
                   AllowSourceMode="False">
```

[image]